# Android Retrofit attempting to make incorrect request on first attempt

Tags: android, retrofit2

We are using retrofit to make API requests in our Android app and are running into a weird issue. I have a request that looks like this:

```
interface apiservice {

    @POST("user/login")
    fun postLogin(@Body body: LoginBody): LiveData<ApiResponseWrapper<LoginRemote>>
```

I make the request by doing:

```
apiservice.postLogin(
    ....
)
```

However, the first time this get's submitted, the request url is:

```
http://localhost/
```

First off, there isn't a single configuration in my app that sets the base url as localhost. Secondly, this request doesn't even have the `/user/login` appended to it.

This was working fine the last time we worked on this app a few weeks ago, but now it has this weird bug when we didn't even touch anything related to this...

**EDIT**

Here is my Retrofit builder

```
Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("${BuildConfig.API_URL}/en/api/v1/")
    .client(makeOkHttpClient(BuildConfig.DEBUG, sessionData))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(LiveDataCallAdapterFactory())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build()
    .create(YTPService::class.java)
```

Here is my Build Config in my :

```
buildConfigField("String", "API_URL", "\"https://myurl.org\"")

// BuildConfig's `DEBUG` gets set to FALSE when build occurs
```

And then this is what is printing out in the log files during this process:

```
// THE FIRST TIME I HIT SUBMIT AND TRIGGER THE REQUEST
D/LOGIN-RESPONSE: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=Response.error(), url=http://localhost/}
    Error(errors=[com.mycompany.myproject.api.auth.login.LoginResponse$ErrorType$Generic@2148520])

... 

// THE SECOND TIME I HIT SUBMIT AND TRIGGER THE REQUEST IMMEDIATELY AFTER FIRST FAILED
D/LOGIN-RESPONSE: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=Logged in as SampleUser1., url=https://myurl.org/en/api/v1/user/login}
    Ok(data=com.mycompany.myproject.api.auth.login.LoginResponse$SuccessData@4f03c75)
```

For even more details, check out this [issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3207) I opened on their repo

**UPDATE**

After looking at the logs on the server, I have confirmed that the proper request is actually being made, but retrofit's ApiResponseWrapper isn't setting the response with the proper information sent back from the server.

e.g.

```
apiservice.postLogin(LoginBody(username, password)).map { // it: ApiResponseWrapper<LoginRemote>

  // `it.response` == Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=Response.error(), url=http://localhost/}

  // When, in fact, the server actually sent back a 200 with the data I need. Retrofit just isn't handling it correct...

}
```

**EDIT 2**

Adding `ApiResponseWrapper` and `LoginRemote` classes as requested

**ApiResponseWrapper**

```
sealed class ApiResponseWrapper<R> {
    companion object {
        fun <R> success(response: Response<R>): ApiResponseWrapper.Success<R> =
                ApiResponseWrapper.Success(response)

        fun <T> failure(error: Throwable): ApiResponseWrapper.Failure<T> =
                ApiResponseWrapper.Failure(error)
    }

    class Failure<T>(val error: Throwable) : ApiResponseWrapper<T>()

    class Success<T>(val response: Response<T>) : ApiResponseWrapper<T>()
}
```

**LoginRemote**

```
class LoginRemote(@SerializedName("user") val user: User) {
    companion object {
        fun parseResponse(response: Response<LoginRemote>): LoginResponse {
            return if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("LOGIN-RESPONSE-BODY", response.body().toString())
                response.body()!!.format()
            } else if (response.code() == 302) {
                // accept terms again
                LoginResponse(listOf(LoginResponse.ErrorType.TermsRequired()))
            } else {
                val errorBody = response.errorBody()?.string()?.trim() ?: ""

                if (errorBody == "[\"Wrong username or password.\"]" || errorBody.contains("has not been activated or is blocked."))
                    return LoginResponse(listOf(LoginResponse.ErrorType.CredentialsInvalid()))
                if (errorBody.contains("[\"Already logged in as "))
                    return LoginResponse(LoginResponse.SuccessData(null, null, null))

                return LoginResponse(listOf(LoginResponse.ErrorType.Generic()))
            }
        }
    }

    fun format(): LoginResponse {
        Log.d("LOGIN-ROLE-KEYS", user.roles.toString())
        val roles = user.roles.keys
        val role = when {
            roles.contains(ROLE_ID_STANDARD) -> Role(ROLE_ID_STANDARD)
            roles.contains(ROLE_ID_LIMITED) -> Role(ROLE_ID_LIMITED)
            else -> Role(ROLE_ID_PREMIUM)
        }
        val countryOfResidence = if (user.countryOfResidence != null) user.countryOfResidence!!.und[0].value else "United Arab Emirates"
        return LoginResponse(LoginResponse.SuccessData(role = role, gender = user.fieldGender, countryOfResidence = countryOfResidence))
    }

    data class User(
            @SerializedName("field_gender") val fieldGender: Gender?,
            @SerializedName("roles") val roles: Map<Int, String>,
            @SerializedName("field_new_residence") val countryOfResidence: CountryOfResidence?
    )

    data class CountryOfResidence(
            @SerializedName("und") val und: List<CountryOfResidenceUND>
    )

    data class CountryOfResidenceUND(
            @SerializedName("value") val value: String
    )

}
```

Comment: Can you post your builder after you get done bashing on Android, lol?

Comment: @RichardDapice Happily, sorry it's just so easy. I also went ahead and added in my log outputs and my build configurations.

Comment: Can you post the code your `ApiResponseWrapper` and `LoginRemote` class?

Comment: @dglozano Yup, take a look under `edit 2`

Comment: @BlondeSwan Hmm it's weird that it works after the first time. Can you please: 1- post how the response with its headers looks like, both when it fails and when it is succesful? 2- Are you sure it returns a 200 code and not a 2xx code when it fails the first time? 3- Does it fail the first time you test it with something else than Android, like with Postman for example?

Comment: @dglozano I am positive that it returns a 200 the first time I make the request. It never fails on anything other than Android. iOS works perfectly fine as expected and so does Postman. This seems to be strictly a Retrofit bug. What I think is going on is that the `Response` I am printing out is just retrofit's default response, and it's being sent back before the response from the server actually gets set.

Comment: Maybe it's some sort of race condition? Like the request returns before the response has been fully written to?

Comment: Hmm I don't know really. Try the following: add a Http interceptor to your OkHttpClient if you don't have one already, try to get the error again and post the detailed log of what is being sent and received.         `HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();`
`httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);`
`okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198957/discussion-between-blondeswan-and-dglozano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I cannot provide a full answer because I am not entirely sure on how everything is implemented, the problem seems to be related to the use of `LiveData` as the return type in your `Retrofit` service. Even though apparently you can do it by creating your custom `Adapter` as shown [in this Medium post](https://medium.com/@pivincii/using-retrofit-with-livedata-5c5a49544ba3), you shouldn't be using an Android Lifecycle aware component so far down in the architecture. **Retrofit shouldn't know anything about Android**. Moreover, it doesn't make sense because `LiveData` it's supposed to expose a value that can change over time, whereas this would be a one-shot use ([check this discussion](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2354))

My suggestion is that you change your API service and use a `RxJava` observable such as `Single` instead. For that, you will have to use [this Adapter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2). Everytime you call the endpoint, you will get a response that can be then manually set into a `LiveData` component.  In turn, that `LiveData` will be observed by your `Activity.`

Comment: I attempted to use RxJava's Observable instead of LiveData as you suggested, and swapped out the Adaptor for the one you suggested, but now the calls are not being made... As soon as I call the service function, execution just stops and there are no okhttp logs suggesting no requests were even made...

Comment: @BlondeSwan you will have to show me how you are calling. Edit your question and add your Repository code

Comment: I went ahead and opened up a new question for this particular issue since it's a different issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57813679/retrofit-observable-response-to-livedata-object-using-subscribe